# Summation by Parts

Tags: summation, summation-by-parts

I am trying to solve $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{2k+1}{k(k+1)}$ using summation by parts:

$\sum u\Delta v=uv-\sum Ev\Delta u$

$u = 2x+1, \Delta v=1/x(x+1)=(x-1)_{-2}$

$v=-(x-1)_{-1}=-1/x$

$\Delta u = 2, Ev = -1/(x+1)$

$\sum\frac{(2x+1)}{x(x+1)}\delta x=\frac{-2x-1}{x}+2\left(\sum x_{-1}\delta x\right)$

Is my solution correct up to this point?  If it is, what is the anti-difference $\sum x_{-1}\delta x$?  This seems to be the finite equivalent to $\int x^{-1}dx=ln(x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your computations are correct, which is easy to see by differencing.

The anti-difference of $x_{-1} = \frac{1}{x+1}$ is known a [Harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number):
$$
    \sum_x \frac{1}{x+1} = H_x
$$
where $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure this fully answers your questions, but it is easier to solve this problem without summation by part, simply by partial fraction expansion:
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k+1}=2H_n-1+\frac{1}{n+1}=2H_n-\frac{n}{n+1}
$$
where $H_n$ is n'th harmonic number

Comment: +1 for suggesting a more elegant method, but your answer is incorrect.  The correct solution is: $2H_n-1+\frac1{n+1}=2H_n-\frac{n}{n+1}$.  You miscalculated what happens at $k=n$.

Comment: @dbyrne: thanks, edited